# Why does this 'if' logic not work in a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sas

I want to enter the following logic in a SQL stored procedure:

```
IF(I2<=13.5,"<=13.5%",
   IF(I2<=14,"13.5% - 14%",
   IF(I2<=14.5,"14% - 14.5%",
   IF(I2<=15,"14.5% - 15%",
   IF(I2<=16,"15% - 16%",
   IF(I2<=18,"16% - 18%",
   IF(I2<=20,"18% - 20%",">20%"))
)
```

The SQL is:

```
COALESCE(
         Case When t1.irr___current <=13.5  then "<=13.5%" else end,
         Case When t1.irr___current <=14  then "13.5% - 14%" else end,
         Case When t1.irr___current <=14.5  then "14% - 14.5%" else end,
         Case When t1.irr___current <=15  then "14.5% - 15%" else end,
         Case When t1.irr___current <=16  then "15% - 16%" else end,
         Case When t1.irr___current <=18  then "16% - 18%" else end,
         Case When t1.irr___current <=20  then "18% - 20%" else ">20%" end)
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Can you elaborate "This is not working" part ?

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to build out where clause information including operators with case statements, this cannot be done at least not in MS SQL, if you need to do something like this you need to build out dynamic sql and execute it. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Kritner- you mean to say, that the above mentioned IF logic can be executed using a where clause?..I didnt get you?, I am a beginner at this, could you please explain a bit in detail?

Comment: Why are you using Coalesce instead of a nested Case ? And i think that your current script can't execute also because you never specified any valid expression for the "else" part

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this perhaps

```
  CASE
        WHEN t1.irr___current IS NULL   THEN '???'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 13.5   THEN '<=13.5%'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 14     THEN '13.5% - 14%'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 14.5   THEN '14% - 14.5%'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 15     THEN '14.5% - 15%'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 16     THEN '15% - 16%'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 18     THEN '16% - 18%'
        WHEN t1.irr___current <= 20     THEN '18% - 20%'
        ELSE '>20%'
  END
```

Comment: Thanks user2067753, I appreciate this. Would you explain me why the second condition didnt work?...i.e the case when _ then " "....end worked, but the second one with case t1.irr followed by when then...didnt work? Infact the second one seems is the more efficient way of writing that code; whats the reason for this anomaly?

Comment: sorry, hadn't noticed these comments. I was curious about the down vote so I looked again and saw I was using double quotes which was wrong. so I changed that. The more abbreviated form I offered initially isn't a form I'm really comfortable with and it does not work in all dbms platforms - which database are you using?

Comment: OK, I cannot get the second form to work using mssql UNLESS I am matching to a specific figure, so comparatives such as <= or between don't seem to work in that form. Pity. Stick to the traditional form.

Comment: SAS Enterprise guide 6.1 => then even more reason to stay with the traditional form; it may seem more verbose; but at least it will work just about anywhere SQL is allowed.

Comment: Got it!!..wierd but interesting. thanks!.Yeah & I dont know why the down vote. Sorry, I am not able to vote as I just joined today. But your suggestion was perfect.

Comment: GReat, it can be marked as answer (I think). Anyway I'm also going to remove the unsuccessful alternative syntax.